# Add a new keyword to Querystring to search in a Document Library

Tags: sharepoint-server, managed-property, sharepoint-search, crawled-property, query-string

I created one managed property that is called **Csearch** and this brings true results when I search for `<managed property>: <property value>.`

I go to Search Center and type this.`Csearch:word`

I can see the result I want in the querystring. `k=Csearch%3Aword`

[image]

And now I want to add new keywords to this querystring.

For example when I type `Csearch:word Sharepoint`in Search Center, I want to see the sharepoint keyword in a querystring with a new name and the `&` symbol.

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to the Keyword Query Language (KQL) syntax, you need to build your query like this:

```
Csearch:word OR Csearch:Sharepoint
```

Reference:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/keyword-query-language-kql-syntax-reference